# google analytics code in dynamic pages with embedded pdfs

Tags: google-analytics

i'm not a programmer. My website has dynamic web pages with embedded pdfs like http://www.indec.gob.ar/uploads/informesdeprensa/emi_10_16.pdf

According to Google Tag Assistant, the GA tracking code is inserted in most of my website http://www.indec.gob.ar, but it is not in the dynamic web pages with embedded pdfs.

Is it possible to insert the GA tracking code in all the dynamic web pages with embedded pdfs? How should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Analytics javascript tracking code cannot be embedded in a pdf, so you are out of luck here.

A possible workaround would be not to have direct links to pdf documents but run requests through an html page that sends a tracking request before the user is redirected to the pdf. Easiest way would be to use a html page with the javascript tracker, or you might alternatively try some serverside download script that send a request via the measurement protocol.